# Stripping out rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I only need to use the controllers, gems etc. If I strip out rails, (the gem, views etc), will it still work properly? What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You should mention that you want to implement API backend if that's your purpose.

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear. Rails has many components - and it depends wildly on what you "strip out" whether thing will work at all. The OP does not mention what his intention is either.

Comment: @max "I only need to use the controllers, gems", I have no requirement for views. Apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Please explain what end result you want to get (is it an API?) because what you wrote so far makes little sense.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel Yeh so I'm just making API requests, accessing a database and doing some calculations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) for that.

> Rails::API is a subset of a normal Rails application, created for applications that don't require all functionality that a complete Rails application provides. It is a bit more lightweight, and consequently a bit faster than a normal Rails application. The main example for its usage is in API applications only, where you usually don't need the entire Rails middleware stack nor template generation.

Comment: Excellent mate, I'll take a look. From a speed perspective, is it probably a good idea to just go with base Ruby/jRuby? Or is the different not too significant?

Comment: Do you mean using different Ruby implementation than Ruby MRI? There's a great effort put into Rubinius and JRuby, some people use them in production, but personally I've never tried that. You can always start with the standard Ruby implementation and move to other if speed becomes a problem.

Comment: `rails-api`'s going to be integrated in Rails 5, so I don't recommend to start with `rails-api`. Rails 5 will be out this Autumn.

Comment: Rails API is stable enough for production and moving over to Rails 5 is not going to be a huge step. I say go for it.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can check out [an opinionated micro-framework for creating REST-like APIs in Ruby](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape)

> Grape is a REST-like API micro-framework for Ruby. It's designed to
>   run on Rack or complement existing web application frameworks such as
>   Rails and Sinatra by providing a simple DSL to easily develop RESTful
>   APIs. It has built-in support for common conventions, including
>   multiple formats, subdomain/prefix restriction, content negotiation,
>   versioning and much more.

**Basic Usage**

> Grape APIs are Rack applications that are created by subclassing
>   Grape::API. Below is a simple example showing some of the more common
>   features of Grape in the context of recreating parts of the Twitter
>   API.

```
module Twitter
  class API < Grape::API
    version 'v1', using: :header, vendor: 'twitter'
    format :json
    prefix :api

    helpers do
      def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.authorize!(env)
      end

      def authenticate!
        error!('401 Unauthorized', 401) unless current_user
      end
    end

    resource :statuses do
      desc 'Return a public timeline.'
      get :public_timeline do
        Status.limit(20)
      end

      desc 'Return a personal timeline.'
      get :home_timeline do
        authenticate!
        current_user.statuses.limit(20)
      end

      desc 'Return a status.'
      params do
        requires :id, type: Integer, desc: 'Status id.'
      end
      route_param :id do
        get do
          Status.find(params[:id])
        end
      end

      desc 'Create a status.'
      params do
        requires :status, type: String, desc: 'Your status.'
      end
      post do
        authenticate!
        Status.create!({
          user: current_user,
          text: params[:status]
        })
      end

      desc 'Update a status.'
      params do
        requires :id, type: String, desc: 'Status ID.'
        requires :status, type: String, desc: 'Your status.'
      end
      put ':id' do
        authenticate!
        current_user.statuses.find(params[:id]).update({
          user: current_user,
          text: params[:status]
        })
      end

      desc 'Delete a status.'
      params do
        requires :id, type: String, desc: 'Status ID.'
      end
      delete ':id' do
        authenticate!
        current_user.statuses.find(params[:id]).destroy
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also check out ruby [json implementations](http://jsonapi.org/implementations/#server-libraries-ruby)
Thanks @oscar for this link

I prefer use [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl)

RABL example:

> Then we can create the following RABL template to express the API
>   output of @posts:

```
# app/views/posts/index.rabl
collection @posts
attributes :id, :title, :subject
child(:user) { attributes :full_name }
node(:read) { |post| post.read_by?(@user) }
```

Output:

```
[{  "post" :
  {
    "id" : 5, "title": "...", "subject": "...",
    "user" : { "full_name" : "..." },
    "read" : true
  }
}]
```

Comment: My vote to this answer! @C. Short : Look also at http://jsonapi.org/implementations if you want to follow `json-api` specs.

Comment: RABL and jbuilder are very sloooow compared to ActiveRecord::Serializers.